# Why is the Fabric repository being abandoned?

Tags: hyperledger

Sorry if this is a duplicate, by why does your GitHub repository for Fabric point me to your Gerrit review system, claiming it's only for legacy purposes? How would one submit PRs now?

Comment: Maybe you should ask them. Why are you asking here?

Comment: @yellowantphil Yeah... I guess I understand the rationale that they officially gave, but their website claims all code is in the GitHub organization.

Comment: Was that supposed to be a reply to Lester? This question seems like product support, which Stack Overflow does not offer. See [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the reasons why the project is moving from GitHub to Gerrit, from Hyperledger Slack channel:

> The rationale for transitioning to Gerrit is to a) provide much more governance over the IP hygiene by enforcing the DCO sign-off on every commit merged (no exceptions). We did not have this level of rigor on GitHub. b) to enforce that no maintainer can merge their own commits. c) to enforce a rule that requires multiple reviewers to agree to a merge.

The maintainers are currently working on the migrations for issues. There should be moved to jira.hyperledger.org

Regarding the pull requests, they must now be submitted on Gerrit:

> To submit code for review, you will need a Linux Foundation ID here:
>   https://identity.linuxfoundation.org/ . Simple enough,if you have an
>   ID, you are set. If not, please create one. This will grant you SSO
>   across the LF tools portfolio.
>
> Add your SSH key to Gerrit
>
> 1. click on your profile (upper right hand corner) and select 'Settings' and then 'SSH Public Keys'
> 2. from a terminal window: pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
> 3. paste into the Gerrit window for your SSH key
> 4. press 'Add' button
>
> So, the new workflow would be as follows:
>
> 1. Clone the Gerrit repository.
> 2. make your changes
> 3. commit your code
> 4. git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master

See [this archive](https://hyperledgerproject.slack.com/archives/fabric/p1469567848000418) for more information.